# Hide zoom buttons in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Is there a way to hide the zoom-in/zoom-out buttons in ArcGIS javascript API? I have external zoom buttons elsewhere on the page, so these are no longer needed.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass in `slider: false` as an option when creating the map. Here is the [Map Options API Reference](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/map-amd.html#map1).

```
map = new Map("map", {
    basemap: "streets",                 
    slider: false
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I did it with:

```
on(map, "load", function () {
        map.hideZoomSlider();
    });
```

Comment: Of course assuming you're sticking with the standard variable names from the samples... ie. *on* and *map*.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone trying to accomplish this using the 4.x versions of the API, try the following when using the MapView (or SceneView) constructor:

```
var view = new MapView ({
    container: "viewDiv",
    map: map,
    ui: {
        components: [ "attribution" ]
    }
});
```

Source: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/view-disable-zoom/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to use method's `showZoomSlider()` / `hideZoomSlider()` property `isZoomSlider`. This should show or hide the zoom slider on the map.

Help link [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/intro_navigation.html). Examples of disabling [here](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/43876).